# reading a csv file in r where the header have commas

Tags: r, excel, csv

In excel when opening the csv, you can see the column names separated by commas
e.g

```
 rabbit,8am,carrot          fox,12am,fish(salmon)
            1                            2
            4                            4
            2                            3
            .                            .
            .                            .
            .                            .
```

When I read this type of file in R, then it reads it as

```
 rabbit..8am.carrot          fox...12am..fish.salmon..
            1                            2
            4                            4
            2                            3
            .                            .
            .                            .
            .                            .
```

Is there any way to read the file so I can get the comas back. I am trying to make variables from the column names by splitting on the commas.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set `check.names = FALSE` when using `read.table`. See `?read.table`

```
> foo <- read.table(text="rabbit,8am,carrot          fox,12am,fish(salmon)
              1                            2
              4                            4", header=TRUE, check.names = FALSE)
> foo
  rabbit,8am,carrot fox,12am,fish(salmon)
1                 1                     2
2                 4                     4
```

Comment: I get an error saying currfile<-read.table(newfile, header=TRUE,check.names = FALSE)
Error in scan(file, what, nmax, sep, dec, quote, skip, nlines, na.strings,  : 
  line 1 did not have 54 elements

Comment: I googled the answer to the error need to add fill = TRUE,sep="," to your solution. Thank you, this solves my problem!